# url rewriting code to remove .php leads to internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/abc/public_html

#To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
#suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini
#php_value mbstring.func_overload 4 # Required for PWSB support. Please  do not uncomment this line. 

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php


Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I have written this code to remove .php from file. Actually its works fine.In some pages while more than 1000 values passed through url it leads to internal server error.I had checked all other possibilities like maximize max_input_vars like so and contacted server team many times.Now they found the issue that my code in .htaccess is not accurate that leads to error.but below 1000 its works fine. Can anybody help me to write a accurate rewrite rule for removing .php..please
Thanks in advance...

Comment: "leads to internal server error" — And the error message reported in your server logs for that is … what?

Comment: @Andy — They're trying to map `/foo` onto `/foo.php` and the code (at a glance, I'm no mod_rewrite expect) looks fine for that.

Comment: There is limit of sending data via url may be you are omitting this that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @Quentin Error 500 - Internal Server Error

An error was encountered while processing your request. Typically this is a temporary condition. Please contact the web site owner for further assistance.

Comment: @Anna — That is the error message typically sent to the browser. It gives very little information because you don't want visitors to your site seeing error messages that give away how the internals of your site work. You need to look at the error message reported **in your server logs**.